# Combining Two SQL Queries - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have two SQL queries:

```
SqlCommand cmdone = new SqlCommand("update HardwareDetails Set Transstat = @Transstat where AssetNo = @AssetNo", con);
cmdone.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Transstat", "Raised");
cmdone.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"AssetNo", txtAsset.Text);
cmdone.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmdone.Dispose();
```

And:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TransferRequest(FrmName,FrmEmpId,ToName) values (@FrmName,@FrmEmpId,@ToName", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmName", txtfrm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmEmpId", Global.transferorid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"ToName", txtName.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Is there a way to combine them into a single query?

Comment: Why would you want to do a silly thing like that?

Comment: Also your `cmd` should be in a `using` block. If your query errors your going to leak memory

Comment: @Liam whats silly about combining multiple SQL statements into a single command?

Comment: What does it gain? It simply breaks the single responsibility principle for no reason

Comment: That is micro-optimisation at best. Again, not a good reason to break the SRP. If you were using a 56k modem then that could be an issue, but it's 2020...

Comment: *there is nothing wrong with it* is breaks the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) and generally leads to worse code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a semi-colon between the two SQL statements, and add all the parameters.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE HardwareDetails SET Transstat = @Transstat WHERE AssetNo = AssetNo; INSERT INTO TransferRequest (FrmName, FrmEmpId, ToName) VALUES (@FrmName, @FrmEmpId, @ToName)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Transstat", "Raised");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"AssetNo", txtAsset.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmName", txtfrm.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmEmpId", Global.transferorid);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"ToName", txtName.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comments:

1. Its best practice (because its safer) to create your `cmd` within a `using` block.
2. [`AddWithValue` should not be used](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), instead create the `SqlParameter` using its constructor and specify the type and precision. E.g. `cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Transstat", SqlDataType.VarChar, 6) { Value = "Raised"});`
3. As pointed out by Liam as it stands this does break the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). Personally I would only use this method if the two statements are linked/related in some way.

Answer (score -1):

```
string query = @"
update HardwareDetails Set Transstat = @Transstat where AssetNo = @AssetNo

Insert into TransferRequest(FrmName,FrmEmpId,ToName) values (@FrmName,@FrmEmpId,@ToName)";


SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(query,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Transstat", "Raised");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"AssetNo", txtAsset.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmName", txtfrm.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"FrmEmpId", Global.transferorid);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"ToName", txtName.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
```

Comment: For the sake of fairness: `cmd` should be in a `using` block.

Comment: he is calling dispose so i saw no need for that

Comment: sigh... If an exception is thrown then Dispose will never get called and that will cause a memory leak...that's why `using` exists

Comment: oooooooh that's a good one, thanks a LOT
there is also this new thing that came out with C# 8 where you can do stuff like ```using var cmd = new sqlcommand()``` and it will make your method act like a using block for cmd

Comment: nah i mean as a keyword
take a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations